# Question regarding statistical methodology that involves logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, nonlinear-regression, methodology

I used following simulated data using R to demonstrate my problem.

```
require(lmtest)
require(splines)
x=rnorm(20 ,0,1)
y=rep(c(0,1),times=10)
```

Although my simulated data has 20 data points, the actual data set has about 75 observations. But the conclusions made based on both data sets are same. So i thought of using this simulated data to demonstrate my problem .

**The summary results based on actual data**

```
summary(X)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.     
  0.000   3.000   4.000   4.588   6.000  10.000
```

The plots between Y and X as follows,

[image]

[image]

**Analysis based on simulated data**

Using this data my goal is to find the best logistic regression model that predicts Y based on X.

My first step is to determine the type of relationship exists between Y and X using likelihood ratio test. That means i tried to determine whether the relationship is linear or non linear between Y and X by fitting following two models. After that likelihood ratio test used to determine which model is significant.

I fitted a regular (linear effects) logistic regression model.

```
fit1=glm(y~x ,family = "binomial")
```

Then to check the non linear effects, i fitted this natural spline model .

```
fit2=glm(y~ns(x,df=2) ,family = "binomial")
```

To determine whether the spline model is significant, i used the likelihood ratio test. The results as follows,

```
Model 1: y ~ x
Model 2: y ~ ns(x, df = 2)
  #Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1   2 -12.952                     
2   3 -12.757  1 0.3912     0.5317
```

Since the p value is large , the linear logistic regression model is significant compared to the non linear natural spline model.

Then i examined the coefficients of logistic regression model,

```
summary(fit1)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.2367     0.4987   0.475    0.635
x            -1.1804     0.9331  -1.265    0.206

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 27.726  on 19  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 25.904  on 18  degrees of freedom
AIC: 29.904
```

So What should be my next step in this situation ? Does this results says that there is no significant relationship between Y and X ? Or should i try some transformations for the independent variable ?

**Important note** : I am so desperate to model this logistic regression model because , using the random forest method  i found that X is an important predictor to predict Y. So I thought that using logistic regression model , I can be explored some relationship (linear or non linear) between Y and X.

Can any one suggest any method to extend my analysis ? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: You have done a great job with just 20 data points.  It looks like you would need more data to go any further.  Note that the random forest isn't particularly trustworthy, given such a small set of data, so what you have are several suggestive analyses that point in the same direction, but not very convincingly.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the comment. Although my simulated data has 20 data points, the actual data set has about 75 observations.The results that observed using actual data and the simulated data is same. So i used this simulated data to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: That changes the question because it affects what you can do.  Please edit your question to conform to the problem you actually have.

Comment: @whuber . I did that. Thank you

Comment: Your question still focuses on the simulation.  Is there any problem with showing summary statistics for the real data?

Comment: @whuber I added summary statistics and descriptive plots between Y and X based on actual data. Hope this will help. Thank you

Comment: The upper xy plot is almost useless, because it does not show us how many observations each dot in the plot represents.  Would the lower one be a smooth of that plot?  If so, what kind of a relation does it suggest to you?

Comment: @whuber The lower plot is a conditional density plot (obtained using cdplot function in R)  . If you see my post, i tried to fit a non linear model too. But that relationship is not significant based on likelihood ratio test.

Comment: Right: indeed, if you were to erect confidence bands around that plot, I bet that a horizontal line would fit neatly through it.  It provides nice graphical support for the conclusion of no detectable relationship.  Absent additional observations or additional variables, what more would you hope to accomplish with these data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93878/discussion-between-student-r123-and-whuber).